# How to take value of checkbox and put it in array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a situation like this:

[image]

What I need to do is to take values of all selected checkboxes and put them in some `JavaScript array` and eventually in `PHP session` afterwards. I have a code like this:

```
    while($userRow=$resultForUsers->fetch_assoc()){
          $nameOfUser=$userRow['users_name'];
          $userId=$userRow['user_facebook_id'];
          $userFBPicture=$userRow['users_picture'];
          echo "
          <tr class='tr-data-users'>
          <td class='text-center'>
          <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value=$userId>
          </td>
          <td class='td-users text-center'>
          <div class='input-group user-name-users'>
          <img class='user-img-users v-t' src=$userFBPicture>
          </div>
          <div class='input-group user-name-users'>
          <h5 id='no-margin'>$nameOfUser</h5>
          </div>
          <div class='input-group user-name-users'>
          <img class='v-t' src='../img/link-icon.png'>
          </div>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class='text-center'>$userId</p>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class='text-center'>113</p>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class='text-center'>19</p>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class='text-center'>19</p>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class='text-center'>39%</p>
          </td>
          <td>
          <p class='text-center'>31.12.2013</p>
          </td>
          </tr>";
}?>
```

So, for each user in my database I'm generating one row, as you can see above, but value of each checkbox has user's id.

```
<td class='text-center'>
              <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value=$userId>
</td>
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't know from where to start. Would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: you can start from https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ or better reading  some book on javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the selected checkbox using [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector in jquery:

```
var userIds = $.map($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function (cb, idx) {
    // here you have the checkbox and you can get the value attribute
    return $(cb).attr('value');
});
```

Alternatively you can use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) on the jquery elements:

```
var userIds = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {
    // here this referes to the checkbox and you can get the value attribute
    return $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: No its not working :S `$(document).ready(function(){
var userIds = $.map($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function (cb, idx) {
    // here you have the checkbox and you can get the value attribute
    return $(cb).attr('value');

});
console.log(userIds);
});` Console.log displays nothing. Am I missing some parameters or what?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(cb)` inside the function?

Comment: @AKS sorry for maybe being very stupid, but my text editor says 'Unreachable code' for `console.log(cb)` inside function, and console displays nothing.

Comment: Please try the second approach  that I have posted and see if that works.

Comment: @itzmukeshy I can't see the result of this code. Maybe I'm `console.log`-ing wrongly.

Comment: @AKS Tried, displays nothing. I think something is missing. Like some `onchange` event that is triggering all of this code of yours. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107742/discussion-between-aks-and-ognj3n).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jquery like below,

```
var allVals = [];  
        $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {  
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
function showChecked(){
  var userIds = $.map($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function (cb, idx) {
    /* here you have the checkbox and you can get the value attribute */
    return $(cb).val();
  });
  console.log(userIds);
  $('#checkedItems').html(userIds.join(', '));
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class='text-center'>
              1 <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value="1">
</td>
<td class='text-center'>
              2 <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value="2">
</td>
<td class='text-center'>
              3 <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value="3">
</td>
<td class='text-center'>
              4 <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value="4">
</td>

<a href="javascript:showChecked();">Show Checked</a>

<div id="checkedItems"></div>
```